# How does applications read my hashed passwords?

Tags: md5, hashing

mpdas (last.fm scrobbler for mpd) forces one to write password hashed in md5. But if it's hashed, how does it login to last.fm? Isn't hash function one-way only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because last.fm does not store your password, they only store the md5 hash of your password (which is still not a very good idea, passwords should be salted and should go through many iterations to slow it down, but maybe they just use the md5 as a starting point before they store it in the database).

They compare the stored md5 to the transmitted md5 and let you log in.

Comment: In other words, it adds practically zero security.

Comment: @grawity I can't believe this is what they do. This is like storing unhashed passwords, where your true password is actually the hash. Plus they oblige you to do the hash for them. Less security, more hassle for the user. Can't be right.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: It might or might not be true – they *could* be storing a strong hash *of* the MD5 hash, server-side (that is, `pbkdf2(md5(password))` or something). I guess someone just felt uncomfortable storing the raw password client-side (and OAuth didn't exist back in the day). So it _does not_ make things _less_ secure, but doesn't make anything _more_ secure either... if anything, it's a false sense of security.